# Weird behavior in a multithread java application (deadlock without lock?)

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, jena

I am having a weird behavior when trying to run multiple threads to collect data in HTTP connections.

In fact, I am trying to process several SPARQL Queries using Jena Semantic Web Framework.

My application uses the following code to create a thread poll:

`final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(X);`

where X is the number of threads I choose.

So, I run a same query at over 2 hundred SPARQL endpoints. This process can be made in a multithreaded environment since each endpoint is (generally) a different server. The latency of each endpoint should allow me create a number of threads much bigger than the number of physical processors I have.

I am having a weird behavior when using a large number of threads. If I use 15 threads, the system will process normally. But, if I use more than 30 threads,for example, the system will stop work. I mean, the log (log4j with async appenders) simply stop getting new messages, the CPU usage went to 0% e nothing more happens.

The first thing I suspected was a deadlock. Using the "Java Visual VM" provided by the java instalation, I saw that each thread continues to run even making nothing! Next thing to do was a thread dump. The result was something like the following for the majority of the threads:

```
pool-2-thread-100" #117 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000000b61c800 nid=0x1e4c in Object.wait() [0x0000000022e0e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:78)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:52)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory.create(QueryFactory.java:40)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(QueryExecutionFactory.java:347)
    at websemantics.UtilitiesSparql.getExecution(UtilitiesSparql.java:378)
    at websemantics.UtilitiesSparql.runSparqlQuery(UtilitiesSparql.java:410)
    at websemantics.UtilitiesSparql.runSparqlQuery(UtilitiesSparql.java:245)
    - locked <0x0000000081268d10> (a websemantics.model.Dataset)
    at websemantics.UtilitiesSparql$SparqlTask.call(UtilitiesSparql.java:75)
    at websemantics.UtilitiesSparql$SparqlTask.call(UtilitiesSparql.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0000000081273738> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

The lock in the middle of the stack is simply a guarantee that only one query will be executed at a time for each endpoint. In the test code it will not happen. As shown in the code above, the state of ALL threads is "RUNNABLE".

As you can see, the code "locks" on the creation of a query object (it will be executed over the network later). To test, I've include a synchronized block were the method QueryFactory.create will be called once a time. In that situation, another part of Jena code (which I don't think it is the responsible) blocks =(

The whole situation is too weird for me and I thought it could be a JVM bug. I did tests on JDK 1.7 (Windows 8 and Server 2012 on a azure machine), JDK 1.8 (today! Windows 8 machine) and OpenJDK 1.7 (Ubuntu 13.*)  and every one had the same behavior. So I don't think it is a JVM bug and probably is my mistake but I can see what I am doing wrong.

Anyone knows when the JVM works that way? The whole thing is driving me crazy!

Thanks very much!

**Update 1: I am adding more information about the problem as asked by others.**

I have run the tool again and made four thread dumps in different times (13:03, 13:04, 13:08 and 13:15). Each one was pretty similar to the others: the code literally freeze after some time. I have uploaded the files to my onedrive: http://1drv.ms/1nGihAF

Most of the threads stopped at the same point of the stack above, but some stopped here:

```
at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:140)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModelWorker(FileManager.java:305)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModel(FileManager.java:258)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesJena.getModelInEverySyntax(UtilitiesJena.java:140)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesJena.getOntologyByURLNonSilently(UtilitiesJena.java:121)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesJena.getOntologyByURLNonSilently(UtilitiesJena.java:54)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesJena.getOntologyByURL(UtilitiesJena.java:184)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesSparql.runSparqlQueryOverDump(UtilitiesSparql.java:299)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesSparql.runSparqlQuery(UtilitiesSparql.java:249)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesSparql$SparqlTask.call(UtilitiesSparql.java:74)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesSparql$SparqlTask.call(UtilitiesSparql.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**The version of Jena I am using is 2.10.0** as my dependency on maven shows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The line 78 of QueryFactory on the first stack is the following (at the arrow -->):

```
   static public Query create(String queryString, String baseURI, Syntax syntax)
   {
78->Query query = new Query() ;
       return parse(query, queryString, baseURI, syntax) ;
   }
```

And the line 144 of ModelFactory on the second stack is:

```
public static Model createDefaultModel()
        144->{ return new ModelCom( Factory.createGraphMem( ) ); }
```

None of the following calls have any synchronized block as far as I can see.

Comment: are most threads at QueryFactory.java:78? what does this line contain? If it is a complex statement, try to split it in several lines.

Comment: Another thing (after checking the code where most threads have stopped) you should try is take several thread dumps and compare them. Probably some pattern should emerge. It may also be helpful to take dumps from the wiring solution to see if anything looks different.

Comment: Hi, I added more information to the question as you asked =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything obvious in Jena that would cause the type of deadlock behaviour you describe.  Firstly what version of Jena is this?

`QueryFactory.create()` at line 78 is merely creating a new instance of an object so possibly you are running into GC problems with the JVM though usually I'd expect to see non-zero CPU usage if that was the case.  Upping the heap size and checking you properly dispose of resources like `QueryExecution` by calling `close()` when you are done with them may help.

You've mentioned that if you `synchronize` the `QueryFactory.create()` calls then you see deadlocks elsewhere, providing this information would help diagnose your problem.  Also posting a complete thread dump in your answer would be useful so we can see what every thread is doing not just the one thread.

Note that there should not be any hard limit on number of concurrent queries with Jena.  At my employer we routinely run test harnesses that use Jena and happily run 100s of concurrent query requests for stress testing.

### Edit

So I think the problem  is that there are `synchronized` blocks in the static class initialisers, see this particular thread from your 1315 dump:

```
"pool-1-thread-62" prio=6 tid=0x0000000029cf7000 nid=0xcbc in Object.wait() [0x000000002f9cd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RIOT.<clinit>(RIOT.java:38)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.IO_Ctl.callByRefection(IO_Ctl.java:54)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.IO_Ctl.init(IO_Ctl.java:36)
    - locked <0x00000006e5bda610> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<clinit>(ModelCom.java:65)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:140)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModelWorker(FileManager.java:305)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager.loadModel(FileManager.java:258)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesJena.getModelInEverySyntax(UtilitiesJena.java:140)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesJena.getOntologyByURLNonSilently(UtilitiesJena.java:121)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesJena.getOntologyByURLNonSilently(UtilitiesJena.java:54)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesJena.getOntologyByURL(UtilitiesJena.java:184)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesSparql.runSparqlQueryOverDump(UtilitiesSparql.java:299)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesSparql.runSparqlQuery(UtilitiesSparql.java:249)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesSparql$SparqlTask.call(UtilitiesSparql.java:74)
    at websemantics.utils.UtilitiesSparql$SparqlTask.call(UtilitiesSparql.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

`ModelCom` has a static class initialiser which calls `IO_Ctl.init()` which calls `RIOT` which has a static class initialiser.  Certainly in the past I know we've had bugs reporting where the chain of static initialisations was getting into a circular reference which would deadlock or things would initialise in the wrong order and break each other.

I know we've fixed bugs in this regard so upgrading to the current stable 2.11.1 release so upgrading from Jena 2.10.0 which is from Feb 2013 to 2.11.1 which is from January 2014 may resolve things.

The other possible workaround you can try is to explicitly call the relevant initialisers yourself before your code goes multithreaded e.g.

```
ARQ.init();
RIOT.init();
```

Comment: Neither I =) Actually, I do not think it is a Jena problem. The version I am using is the 2.10.0 but I will test with the most recent version.

Comment: About the synchronized block, I am unable to do this right now but at night I will, then I put here more information. Thanks very much!

Comment: Ok, I think I see what may be the problem, see my edited answer

Comment: Hi! I really tried to upgrade the version and my tool was able to run properly =) Thanks very much!

The question is: the thread dump shouldn't show this threads as blocked in these situation? I mean, I never got a deadlock inside a static block so this behavior is very weird =)